# Powershell -gt and -lt when comparing dates instead of months

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build an automatic script that does a few things.
This script should run every midnight but only trigger once.

1. Grant access to their mailbox to their manager
2. Notify the manager that access has been granted
3. Remove all user groups of that user.

However, it doesn't seem to work as I want.
Right now I have a test user that has been modified yesterday. 02-27-2022 which is greater than 02-26-2022, but it doesn't trigger. Can anyone see why?

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).Date
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=testOU,DC=fire,DC=cloud" -Properties Name, Modified, Manager | Select-Object Name,Manager
ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Modified.Date -gt $refDate) {
        Add-MailboxPermission -Identity ($_.Name) -User ($_.Manager) -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -Confirm:$false
        $manageradd = (Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties Mail | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Mail)
        Send-MailMessage -From 'test@test.com' -To $manageradd -Subject 'Employee' -Body "something something" -SmtpServer 'server' -encoding utf8
        $SearchBase = "OU=testOU,DC=fire,DC=cloud"
        $Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties MemberOf
        ForEach($User in $Users){
        $User.MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Member $User -Confirm:$false }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a pipe missing on your second code line and you filter away everything except of  Name and Manager but you're trying to chekc the condition for the *modified* attribute.

Comment: Add some logging to show username and modified date in your foreach-object - perhaps the OU filter in GetADUser is skipping your test user.

Comment: Why use Get-ADUser again to get the users in that OU? You could get the `MemberOf` property straight away in the call: `Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=testOU,DC=fire,DC=cloud" -Properties Name, Modified, MemberOf, Manager | ForEach-Object { .. }`